# Django Model Inheritance and Admin System

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I'm trying to build a system for managing the various types of content in a page.  For example, a page may have text content, hyperlink content, video content, ect.

In my modeling code, I have a base class:

```
class ContentItem(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    page_order = models.IntegerField()
    last_update_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())

    class Meta:
      abstract = True
      ordering = ['page_order', 'last_update_date', 'title']
```

This is the base class for all content items.  The page order controls what position it is on the page, for example the item with page_order = 0 should be at the top of the page.  Next I define a few specific content models that inherit from this one.

```
class LinkContent(ContentItem):
  url = models.URLField()
  link_text = models.CharField(max_lenth=1000)

class TextContent(ContentItem):
 text = models.CharField()


class VideoContent(ContentItem):
      title = models.CharField()
      video_file = models.FieldField(upload_to = 'videos')
```

There could be many more such content types.  Then I would define a Page model that is composed of all the various content types.  Ideally, I could put all the types in on relation based on the base type.  So in this one relation you would have a mixture of LinkContents, TextContents, and VideoContents.  They would be sorted by page_order to determine their order on the page when rendering the template.

```
class Page(models.Model):
  contents = models.ManyToManyField(ContentItem)
  title = models.CharField()
```

Is there any way to make such a scheme work?  Or is it problematic to have one relation with different types of models in it?  I know this is a good solution from and object oriented programming standpoint, basically using polymorphism to my advantage, but I am not sure it makes sense at the database level.

Do I instead need something more like this:

```
class Page(models.Model):
  video_contents = models.ManyToManyField(VideoContent)
  link_contents = models.ManyToManyField(LinkContent)
  text_contents = models.ManyToManyField(TextContent)
  title = models.CharField()
```

I know this would work, but my scheme of determining the placement of the objects on the page becomes more difficult.  I would need to traverse all the content relations, sort them by page_order and then render them.

I think in both cases, I want to declare a render() method on the base class that each specific content type can inherit.  This way if I have a list of ContentItems I can use duck typing to render them without worrying about their specific type.

My final question is how do I make admin place nice with this?  How would I make an easy way to see all of the ContentItems that make up a page in one view, so they can easily be moved around by changing page_order?

Thanks for reading of this, let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a fine way to do it.  Unfortunately, Django's ORM doesn't handle model inheritance as smoothly as you might want.  `page.contents` will contain a QuerySet of `Content` objects. If you want to access the subtypes, you need to create some way of downcasting a content object.  The problem is that this requires an query per object, which can rapidly get out of hand.  [This blog post](http://jeffelmore.org/2010/11/11/automatic-downcasting-of-inherited-models-in-django/) describes a technique for getting the mixed subtypes in one queryset, using `select_related()` behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks @jcdyer. That was very helpful information. One thing I am still unclear on though is how I would make this work in the Admin interface. Ideally, I would like a way to list the Page's contents and have the appropriate admin form be shown for the item based on the specific class. For example, If a Page has 2 LinkContents and 1 TextContent in it's contents attribute, I want the first two to be editable with the Link form and the other with the text form. Is there a simple way to do something like this? I've done a lot of admin customization, but never seen anything like that.