# abstract model inlines in django admin

Tags: django-models, django-admin

could any please suggest how best to achieve below functionality
i searched stackoverflow and google, but am not sure if i came up with an answer

---

models.py:

```
class Collection(models.Model):
    pass

class Item(models.Model):
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Item1(Item):
    name = models.CharField()

class Item2(Item):
    length = models.IntegerField()
```

---

in admin.py

Q: would it be possible in the admin model for "Collection", if there were some way to inline "Items" and in the inlines allow choice of Item1 or Item2 (or more).
so multiple subtypes of "Item" could be linked to the same collection from the same admin page.

TIA

edit: found info on this link to be a bit useful, (it seems to give functionality approximately to what was request)
[Django Admin Changing Inline Admin Form based on class type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383332/django-admin-changing-inline-admin-form-based-on-class-type?lq=1)

but am unsure if this is exactly what i had asked in the question